# Basic commands of rails 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I started in rails with version 2.3.5 with a tutorial. Some of the commands do not work, for example:

```
$ rails generate controller welcome index
```

This does not work as the tutorial is using another version. Can some one suggest the basic commands of v2.3.5?

Comment: Is upgrading to rails 3.2 or 4 not an option? Rails 2.3 is quite old at this point and I would not recommend starting a new application with it.

Comment: The matter is product which i have to work is on v2.3.5

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer can be easily found in Rails documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you are starting with Rails you should not be trying to learn 2.3. That said, in 2.3 all comands are in the `script` directory:

```
$ ls -1 script
about
console
dbconsole
destroy
generate
performance
plugin
runner
server
```

You can run them like this:

```
ruby script/generate controller welcome index
```

You can learn more about each command using `--help`, for example:

```
ruby script/generate --help
Usage: script/generate generator [options] [args]
...
```

API documentation for 2.3 is [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/) and Rails Guides for 2.3 are [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/)